# Label se auto ajustar com o tamanho do texto swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

Eu tenho um label dentro de um scrollView, e este label recebe um N textos, uns são pequenos e outros grandes por isso a ideia foi colocar no scrollView, mais o problema é que não consigo ajustar o label para aumentar conforme o texto, ele corta o restante da linha. O scrollView não é grande é apenas uma pequena parte da tela.

Ja tentei assim no código, mais não deu certo

```
 @IBOutlet weak var svPergunta: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblPergunta: UILabel!

var sPergunta = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    lblPergunta.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lblPergunta.text = sPergunta
    lblPergunta.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    svPergunta.contentSize.height = 200

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A alternativa que eu encontrei para meu problema e no caso muito melhor do que o Label foi usar TextView assim eliminei o ScrollView também usando apenas um componente na tela.

```
import UIKit

class ViewPerguntas: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var lblPergunta: UITextView!

var sPergunta = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    lblPergunta.text = sPergunta
    lblPergunta.editable = false
    lblPergunta.selectable = false

   }

}
```